# jQuery string split the string after the space using split() method

Tags: javascript, jquery

my code

```
  var str =$(this).attr('id');
```

this will give me value == **myid 5**

```
   var str1 = myid
   var str2 = 5
```

i want something like this ..

how to achieve this using split method

Comment: As a side-note: I don't think id values should contain spaces.

Comment: As a side-note: To get ID from `this` element you may simply use `this.id`.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

```
var str =$(this).attr('id');
var ret = str.split(" ");
var str1 = ret[0];
var str2 = ret[1];
```

Answer (score 2):

Use in-built function: split()

```
var source = 'myid 5';

//reduce multiple places to single space and then split
var splittedSource = source.replace(/\s{2,}/g, ' ').split(' ');

console.log(splittedSource);
```

​
Note: this works even there is multiple spaces between the string groups

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/QNSyr/6/

Answer (score 1):

One line solution:

```
//<div id="mypost-5">
var postId = this.id.split('mypost-')[1] ); //better solution than the below one!
```

-OR-

```
//<div id="mypost-5">
var postId = $(this).attr('id').split('mypost-')[1];
```

Answer (score 0):

If there is one or more spaces between,

```
var str = $(this).attr('id');
var array = str.split(/\s+/g);
var str1 = array[0];
var str2 = array[1];
```